# remove ticker for individual object in createjs

Tags: jquery-animate, createjs, ticker

I want to remove the listener for individual objects that are animating. I want to remove the ticker for individual objects because they will stop at different times when they reach 200px in y. This code is one frame in Adobe Animate. So this code is not working:

```
this.stop();

that= this;

var aParticle;
var mySpeed = 12;
var myRotation = 4;
var totalParticles = 5;
var stopParticles = false;
var particleHolder = new createjs.Container();
var count = 0;

var collission_ar = [this.parent.mc_coll0, this.parent.mc_coll1, `this.parent.mc_coll2, this.parent.mc_coll3, this.parent.mc_coll4,     this.parent.mc_coll5, this.parent.mc_coll6, this.parent.mc_coll7, this.parent.mc_coll8, this.parent.mc_coll9, this.parent.mc_coll10, this.parent.mc_coll11, this.parent.mc_coll12, this.parent.mc_coll13, this.parent.mc_coll14];`
var totalCollisions = collission_ar.length;
this.addChild(particleHolder);


//stage.update();

var xRange = width;
var yRange = height;

var scaleNum = 1;
//var collisionMethod = ndgmr.checkPixelCollision;

this.scaleX = 1;
this.scaleY = 1;

createParticles()

setTimeout(function(){
    removeTimer();
}, 5000)

function createParticles(){

    var particle_ar = [];
    var randNum = Math.ceil(Math.random() * totalParticles);

    aParticle = new lib['MC_leaf'+randNum]();
    aParticle.name = 'MC_leaf'+count;
    aParticle.x = Math.random() * xRange;
    aParticle.y = -Math.random() * 15;

    theNum = Math.random() * scaleNum;
    aParticle.scaleX = theNum
    aParticle.scaleY = theNum
    aParticle.alpha = 1;
    aParticle.collision = Math.floor(Math.random() * 2);
    particleHolder.addChild(aParticle);
    aParticle.addEventListener("tick", animateParticle.bind(that));
    if(!stopParticles){
        timer = setTimeout(function() { createParticles() }, 100);
    }
    count++;
}

function animateParticle (event){
    var part = event.currentTarget;

    event.currentTarget.y += mySpeed
    event.currentTarget.x += Math.random()/10
    event.currentTarget.rotation += myRotation;

    if (part.y > 200) { 

        if(part.name == 'MC_leaf0') console.log('part0 y '+part.y); 
        part.removeEventListener("tick", animateParticle.bind(that));
    }

}

function removeTimer() {
    stopParticles = true;
    timer = clearInterval();

}


var timer = setTimeout(function() { createParticles() }, 100, that);
```

So this code is just ignored:
part.removeEventListener("tick", animateParticle.bind(that));

Answer (score 0):

You must pass a reference to the same method in `removeEventListener` that you used with `addEventListener`. When you use `bind`, it generates a wrapper function each time.

```
// This won't work.
part.removeEventListener("tick", animateParticle.bind(that));
```

A simple workaround is to store a reference to the bound function, and use that.

```
aParticle.tickHandler = animateParticle.bind(that);
aParticle.addEventListener("tick", aParticle.tickHandler);
```

Then use it when removing the listener

```
part.removeEventListener("tick", part.tickHandler);
```

There is a better way to handle this though. If you use the utility `on()` method instead of `addEventListener`, you can easily remove the method inside the handler.

```
aParticle.on("tick", animateParticle, that);

// Then when removing:
function animateParticle(event) {
    if (conditions) {
        event.remove();
    }
}
```

---

The `on()` method also has a `scope` parameter, so you can skip the function binding. It is important to note though that the `on()` method does its own internal binding, so to remove a listener the usual way, you have to store a reference to it as well.

```
var listener = target.on("tick", handler, this);
listener.off("tick", listener);
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: In the same code above, I I change the timer that creates the particles to a setInterval, I lose scope and can't find how to stop the interval.

    var timer = setTimeout(function() { createParticles() }, 100, that);

Eventually the code goes to the function:
    function removeTimer() {
        stopParticles = true;
        timer = clearInterval();

    }

timer here will not clearInterval. What am I doing incorrectly?